# Cuda for loop doubts

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia

I worked on the for loop, which inside the cuda kernel functions.  I split the data into row and columns.  I can't understand that why "fillFirstCells_kernel" cannot provide me the correct result. The "fillFirstCells_kernel1" function is provided the expected result.

Any comments.

Below is the code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS    10
#define COLS    4

__global__ void fillData_kernel(int len,
                                unsigned int* data)
{
    int offset = blockIdx.x + blockDim.x * threadIdx.x;

    if (offset < len)
    {
        data[offset] = offset;

        offset += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

__global__ void fillFirstCells_kernel(unsigned int *data,
                                      unsigned int *result)
{
    int offset = blockIdx.x + blockDim.x * threadIdx.x;

    while (offset < ROWS)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            result[offset] += data[offset*COLS+i];      
            //result[offset] += data[offset*COLS];
            //atomicAdd(&result[offset], 1);
        }

        offset += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

__global__ void fillFirstCells_kernel1(unsigned int *data,
                                      unsigned int *result)
{
    int offset = blockIdx.x + blockDim.x * threadIdx.x;

    if (offset < ROWS)
    {
        result[offset] = data[offset*COLS] + 
                         data[offset*COLS+1] +
                         data[offset*COLS+2] +
                         data[offset*COLS+3];

        //offset += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

void displayIntOutput(unsigned int* data)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("%08x ", data[i*COLS+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}


void main()
{
    unsigned int *h_data, *h_filled_data;
    unsigned int *d_filled_data;

    int size = ROWS * COLS * sizeof(unsigned int);

    h_data = (unsigned int*)malloc(size);
    h_filled_data = (unsigned int*)malloc(size);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_filled_data, size);
    cudaMemset(d_filled_data, 0, size);

    dim3 threads(8, 1);
    dim3 blocks(ceil((float)size/(float)threads.x), 1);

    fillData_kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(size, d_filled_data);

    cudaMemcpy(h_filled_data, d_filled_data, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    displayIntOutput(h_filled_data);


    unsigned int *h_first_item_in_col;
    unsigned int *d_first_item_in_col;

    h_first_item_in_col = (unsigned int*)malloc(ROWS*sizeof(int));
    memset(h_first_item_in_col, 0, ROWS*sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_first_item_in_col, ROWS*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(d_first_item_in_col, 0, ROWS*sizeof(int));

    dim3 threads_first(8, 1);
    dim3 blocks_first(ceil((float)(ROWS*sizeof(int))/(float)threads_first.x), 1);

    fillFirstCells_kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(d_filled_data, d_first_item_in_col);

    cudaMemcpy(h_first_item_in_col, d_first_item_in_col, ROWS*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
        printf("%d. %08x\n", (i+1), h_first_item_in_col[i]);

    cudaFree(d_filled_data);
    cudaFree(d_first_item_in_col);

    free(h_data);
    free(h_filled_data);
    free(h_first_item_in_col);

    system("pause");
}
```

**Output of kernel "fillFirstCells_kernel":**

00000000 00000001 00000002 00000003
00000004 00000005 00000006 00000007
00000008 00000009 0000000a 0000000b
0000000c 0000000d 0000000e 0000000f
00000010 00000011 00000012 00000013
00000014 00000015 00000016 00000017
00000018 00000019 0000001a 0000001b
0000001c 0000001d 0000001e 0000001f
00000020 00000021 00000022 00000023
00000024 00000025 00000026 00000027

1. 00000006
2. 00000016
3. 00000026
4. 00000036
5. 00000046
6. 00000056
7. 00000066
8. 00000076
9. 0000010c
10. 0000012c

**Output of kernel "fillFirstCells_kernel":**

00000000 00000001 00000002 00000003
00000004 00000005 00000006 00000007
00000008 00000009 0000000a 0000000b
0000000c 0000000d 0000000e 0000000f
00000010 00000011 00000012 00000013
00000014 00000015 00000016 00000017
00000018 00000019 0000001a 0000001b
0000001c 0000001d 0000001e 0000001f
00000020 00000021 00000022 00000023
00000024 00000025 00000026 00000027

1. 00000006
2. 00000016
3. 00000026
4. 00000036
5. 00000046
6. 00000056
7. 00000066
8. 00000076
9. 00000086
10. 00000096

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of mistakes you have made.

```
int offset = blockIdx.x + blockDim.x * threadIdx.x;
```

should be:

```
int offset = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

When launching a kernel you should launch one thread per element and not byte.

```
dim3 blocks(ceil((float)size/(float)threads.x), 1);
```

should be

```
dim3 blocks(ceil((float)ROWS*COLS/(float)threads.x), 1);
```

The length argument to kernel function is wrong:

```
fillData_kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(size, d_filled_data);
```

should be:

```
fillData_kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(ROWS*COLS, d_filled_data);
```

I guess that's it.